# How to install multiple apks at a time?

Tags: android

Am developing one Android application which is using thinkfreeoffice.apk for viewing documents in my application. My requirement is I have to download both my application and thinkfreeoffice apks at a time and also install both these apks at a time.

anybody did this one before?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot literally, unless your application is signed with the system certificate or you are using the SDK/ADB install method from a connected PC, or you find and abuse some security bug.  As a security measure, any installation done by a normal application on the phone will require the user to go through the confirmation dialog one app at a time.

What you can do is put check in your application for the one it depends on, and keep complaining/downloading/ACTION_VIEWing the downloaded package upon startup of your app until the user either decides they don't want to use your app or agrees with the system install dialogue for the app you depend on.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to install multiple applications at the same time, as the user has to confirm installation for each apk.

You could of course make the user install your application first, then ask the user to install the office application after which you use an intent to start the installation or redirect them to the Market.

Similar implementations have been used in applications that use third party barcode scanning or speech recognition.